# Previous Step in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I want to create a Previous function in AngularJS. I have created Single page application which consists of form and the form has multiple steps. I have used this code to create my steps in form.

```
<form name='myform' id="myform" ng-init="step = 1" ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)">
    <div ng-show="step==1">
    <div ng-form='step1form'>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have got this online but I don't understand how do make it work in AngularJS. In this online form, they have created a fieldset. I have made steps. How do I make previous function like this?

```
    $(".previous").click(function(){
    //if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `step` variable to a controller and then increment/decrement it when you want to move from one form to another:

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"
    <!-- no ng-init anymore -->
    <form name='myform' id="myform"
          ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)">
        <div ng-show="step==1">
          <div ng-form='step1form'>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button ng-show="step > 1" ng-click="previous()">Previous</button>
        <button ng-show="step < maxStep" ng-click="next()">Next</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.step = 1;
    $scope.maxStep = 100; // <-- Maximum num. of steps in the form.

    $scope.previous = function() { $scope.step -= 1; }
    $scope.next = function() { $scope.step += 1; }
}
```

The animations *should* in principle change to CSS animations which are triggered by `.ng-enter/.ng-leave` classes. Otherwise, you would need custom directives.

Comment: I can not just decrement. Because sometimes my step4 previous can be step1 or step25. In this case how can i do the previous function

Comment: Create a lookup dictionary which maps each step to the previous step.

Comment: thanks. but i have no idea about the lookup dictionary.. Can you provide me any reference related to previous function?